# How to get email of authenticated user

Tags: php, ldap

I am able to authenticate users using ldap. However in my application I need to be able to e-mail the authenticated user and their e-mail address can sometimes differ from their username and so I would like to query ldap for that user's email address. I am confused on the syntax, my server is ldap://test.tester.net. So would my $base_dn be:

```
$base_dn = "OU=test,OU=tester,DC=net";
```

and my filter be:

```
$filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=IM-ALL_USERS))";
```

Then query the results to get the mail header?

Thanks for any input